# How to interpret output of quantile regression with interaction terms?

Tags: interaction, econometrics, interpretation, spss, quantile-regression

I'm running a quantile regression on SPSS to examine changes in the income structure over time in a certain profession, specifically trying to see if there is an increasing income inequality by eploring differences in the rates of change in different income groups.

*Dataset*

So the dependent variable is the indexed income.
The independent variables are demographic categories, profession segments and the time variable (quarter in this dataset).
I've also let dummies of all categorical variables interact with quarter and added to the model, for example: agegroup_i *quarter, ethnicity_j *quarter, segment_k *quarter, etc.

*Output*

Given the average income has increased across the entire profession, coefficients of higher-earning categories are mostly larger than those of lower-earning categories, and coefficients of higher quantiles are also larger than those of lower quantiles.
For example:

- coeffs for segm_data_science*quarter: 4 for 10%Q, 12 for 90%Q
- coeffs for segm_data_analytics*quarter: 5 for 10%Q, 8 for 90%Q
- coeffs for segm_data_entry*quarter: -2 for 10%Q, 3 for 90%Q
  (all coeffs are significant)

*Would it then be correct to conclude that:*

1. The higher bound of the income distribution has seen a bigger increase/ faster growth in income compared with the lower bound. In other words, higher earners are earning increasingly more than the lower earners.
2. There is a growing gap of income in this profession. In other words, there is an increasing income inequality in this profession.

If such conclusions cannot be drawn, then how should the results be interpreted or what can be said about the structural changes of the income distribution?

Comment: Somehow [crossposted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65540125/how-to-find-out-whether-coefficients-of-different-quantiles-are-significantly-di).